# How to make endpoints on slider move html

Tags: html, slider

I am trying to make a slider to make a selection from a price range.

This is my HTML code

```
                                   <div class="search-price-collateresult">
                                        <div style="clear:both;" id="PriceSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
                                            <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;">
                                            </div>
                                            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;">
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;">
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="range">
                                            <div style="width: 55px; left: 0%; position: absolute; top: 11px; margin-left: 0px;" id="leftP">€5</div>
                                            <div style="left: 100%; top: 11px; position: absolute; margin-left: -0.6em;" id="rightP">€30</div>
                                            <div style="left:0%;position: absolute;top:11px;margin-left: -0.6em;display:none;" id="leftST">5</div><div style="left: 100%; top: 11px; position: absolute; margin-left: -0.6em;display:none;" id="rightST">
                                                30
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle{
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background:url(Images/) no-repeat; overflow: hidden; 
    position:absolute;
    top: -10px;
    border-style:none; 
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 1px;
}

.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.ui-slider {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 0.76923em;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1.15385em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1.15385em;
    z-index: 2;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    background-color: #da4d4d;
    margin-left: -0.6em;
    top: -0.5em;
}

.search-price-collateresult {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 0 0px 0;
}

a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: inherit;
}

a:focus
{
    outline:none;
}

a:hover
{
    color:black;
}
```

The slider is being displayed exactly as I want it to however when the range buttons are being clicked they cannot be moved.

Do I have to create some form of script? or can this be controlled using CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, just a lengthy comment.

(1) You haven't really provided enough of your slider HTML and js for us troubleshoot. Is it a self-written slider, or one you downloaded? *If so, which one?*

(2) You have mixed inline CSS with external CSS. Bad idea. In fact, inline CSS *(`style=""`)* is always a bad idea.

(3) How should this slider work? What do you want to happen when the user clicks on `leftP` or `leftST`? What are those supposed to do?

(4) You are right: most sliders work with javascript/jQuery. That is the only method for the web page to detect a user click and do something.

(5) An observation: you are using `left:0%` with assigning a `position` to the element. `top:` `left` etc only work do not work on elements with `position:static`, which is the default unless changed. Many of us do something like this at the top of our CSS:

```
* {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;}
```

(6) Please edit the below jsFiddle and make it closer to your final desired product. As your question is written, I cannot see how to help you further.

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ha9L65zr/)